# Factorised groups and actions

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let G be a group that can be written as a product of two of its subgroups, that is
$$G = MN = \{mn~~|~~m\in M, n\in N\}.$$
Now let $k$ be a field, let $k(N)$ be the dual space of $N$ (here, the dual space means the collection of functions from $N$ to $k$) and $kM$ the group algebra of $M$.

We have that $M$ has an action on $N$ and $N$ also has an action on $M$. These actions induce an action of $k(N)$ on $kM$ and an action of $kM$ on $k(N)$.

I want to know how these actions are possible.

Comment: What are "k(N)" and "kM"?

Comment: k(N) is the dual space of N, and kM is the group algebra of M

Comment: What exactly does "factorized group" mean? Where did the letter H go, and where did the letter M come from? Are M and N groups? Do their actions on each other respect the group operation, or...? Do their actions on each other have something to do with G? By "dual space of N" do you mean the vector space of k-valued functions on N, where k is a field? (Or perhaps the algebra of functions, with pointwise addition and multiplication.) You need to improve your question so we can understand it.

Comment: @runway44, I have made changes to the question, I hope this makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what $G$ has to do with this, but let's say $M$ and $N$ are two groups which each have a group action on the other (with no assumption about how $M\curvearrowright N$ respects $N$'s group operation, or vice-versa).

I will use $k^N$ to refer to the algebra of functions $N\to k$ (where $k$ is a field) with pointwise addition and pointwise multiplication of functions as its operations.

Since $M$ acts on $N$, we can say $M$ acts on $k^N$ by algebra automorphisms. Given $f:N\to k$ and any element $m\in M$, the function $m\cdot f$ is defined by $(m\cdot f)(n)=f(m^{-1}n)$ for all $n\in N$. You could call this a sort of "contragredient" action I guess. You can check it respects the pointwise operations on $k^N$.

Given a linear action of a group $M$ on a vector space $V$, that automatically means there is a representation of $kM$ on $V$, by linear extension. That is, $(\sum c_m m)v:=\sum c_m(mv)$. For $V=k^N$ that means

$$ \big((\sum_{m\in M} c_m m)f\big)(n):=\sum_{m\in M} c_m f(m^{-1}n) $$

for all $n\in N$ and $f:N\to k$.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it was really helpful